Find vectors to show that the ratio of the relative error in the b to the relative error in solution is maximized
I am being asked to find vectors $\delta b$, $x$, $\delta x$ and $b$ such that given an invertible matrix $A$, $(\frac{||\delta b||_{\infty}}{||b||_{\infty}})/(\frac{||\delta x||_{\infty}}{||x||_{\infty}})$ is maximized. I am trying to utilize the Theorem where enter image description here
But I realized because the numerator and denominator are swapped, the ratio is being maximized at $1/K(A)$ instead of $K(A)$. Since I have no control over $A$ I can't really minimize $K(A)$ since I can't change $||A||_{\infty}$ or $||A^{-1}||{\infty}$, does that mean I am supposed to proceed with the problem as if it's bounded by $K(A)$? Thank you in advance.
